# Rendering array with duplicate values in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#chat",
  data: {
    messages: [],
    message: ''
  },
  methods: {
    add: function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      this.messages.push(this.message);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.24/vue.min.js"></script>
<form id="chat">
  <ul id='message'>
    <li v-for="msg in messages">{{msg}}</li>
  </ul>

  <input v-model="message">
  <button v-on:click="add">add</button>
</form>
```

After run the code, if I add the duplicated data, the Vue only display the the value once in the last.

for example.
type:

- abc
- a
- abc

display:

- a
- abc

If I refactor and use object to instead of primary value, it's work as expected event they have duplicated object.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b42dohdu/1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `track-by="$index"`. ([manual](https://vuejs.org/guide/list.html#track-by))

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#chat",
  data: {
    messages: [],
    message: ''
  },
  methods: {
    add: function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      this.messages.push(this.message);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.24/vue.min.js"></script>
<form id="chat">
  <ul id='message'>
    <li v-for="msg in messages" track-by="$index">{{msg}}</li>
  </ul>

  <input v-model="message">
  <button v-on:click="add">add</button>
</form>
```